# checkbox habilitada/desabilitada segundo informação do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Resumindo, fiz uma página que faz reservas de equipamentos, funciona normalmente.
Inicialmente, são três equipamentos, Notebook, Projetor e Webcam escolhidos através de checkbox.

São 2 notebooks disponíveis, 2 projetor e 10 webcams.

Eu estou tentando solucionar uma forma, onde duas reservas de notebooks podem ser feitas, mas ao tentar fazer a reserva de um terceiro notebook, a checkbox dele fica inabilitada, ou seja, não tem mais notebook disponíveis até que a data de validade da reserva finalize e libere uma possibilidade de reserva. Possuo no banco dataini, horaini, datafim e horafim, isso deverá acontecer com projetor e webcam

A cosulta no banco para saber se há reservas incluindo aquele equipamento eu fiz (mas como sou iniciante com boa vontade, travei) mas não sei como prosseguir no input.

DIV das checkbox:

```html
                    <div>
                        <label for="Notebook" for="projetor">Equipamentos: </label>
                        <div class="input-control text size4">

                            <input class="text" type="checkbox" name="notebook" id="notebook" value="Notebook" /> Notebook
                            <input class="text" type="checkbox" name="projetor" id="projetor" value="Projetor" /> Projetor
                            <input class="text" type="checkbox" name="webcam" id="webcam" value="Webcam" /> Webcam
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

PHP:

```php
    $sql_qtde = "SELECT * FROM `reservas` WHERE (notebook = 'notebook') AND datafim = CURRENT_DATE";
    $query_qtde = mysqli_query($link, $sql_qtde);
    while($busca_notebook = mysqli_affected_rows($query_qtde)){

           if($busca_notebook ==0){



           }else{

           }

        }
```

Comment: Tentando entender o seu problema, você tem disponibilidade de equipamentos limitada, terá um fluxo continuo de entra e saída desse equipamento, terá vários clientes conectados simultaneamente em seus respectivos navegadores disputando os equipamentos e toda a vez que a disponibilidade chegar a zero o servidor precisa comunicar a todos navegadores conectados ao seu site que o equipamento está indisponível e devem alterar elementos na página visualizada. Se minha análise condiz com seu cenário você usar WebSockets para propagar mensagens do servidor aos clientes.

Comment: Augusto, obrigado por comentar. Não uso WebSockets, e sua analise de entendimento está correta. MAs a aplicação que fiz é coisa simples, feito para uma intranet mesmo, onde as pessoas vão saber a disponibilidade do equipamento antes mesmo de agendar, caso esteja habilitada. Eu consegui, de certa forma, resolver o problema, ainda preciso de alguns ajustes, mas funciona. Solução foi próxima do que eu já havia postado e mais algumas coisas.

Comment: Eu escrevi errado a ultima frase, eu queria dizer que você deve usar websockets para realizar o precisa ser feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção para resolver seu problema é adicionar uma coluna no banco de dados como Boolean, verificando o status do equipamento, se está disponível no momento ou não.

Caso o campo seja true, você habilita o checkbox, caso seja falso desabilita.

Comment: Gabriel, obrigado pela ajuda. Sua ideia é interessante, não fiz dessa forma, ainda estou fazendo alguns ajustes de validação, mas se eu precisar, vou tentar fazer assim.